# php thumbnail error

Tags: php, image, resize, thumbnails

I'm trying to resize an image and display as thumbnail using Php Thumbnail. I keep getting the error, "image cannot be displayed because it contains errors". Does anyone have any idea what's wrong?

```
  <?php  


 require_once('phpthumb2/ThumbLib.inc.php');

    require "db_connection.php"; 

    $iii = 1;

    $imagequery = mysql_query("SELECT source FROM photos ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 16");
    $imageSrc = mysql_result($imagequery,$iii,'source');
    $thumb = PhpThumbFactory::create($imageSrc);  
    $thumb->resize(100,100);
     $thumb->show();  

?>
```

Comment: depending on the size of the image, if your storing it in a text filed, the text field may have cut off some of the image data.

Answer (score 1):

Look in the image's source code. You're likely to have a PHP error in it. Possibly from the mySQL query, for which it would be a good idea to add error checking using `mysql_error()`.

Alternatively, look for the line in the PHPThumb file where it emits the `Content-type` header and comment it out. Then you should get the image's source code, along with any PHP errors.

Should there be no error messages, another possible reason for this is that the image is in the wrong format - most browsers support only a very basic set of image formats (JPG, GIF, PNG). Internet Explorer doesn't support CMYK images.

Comment: I don't think that's the problem. It works for some images. For any image above 1mb, it has failed. I've tried three times now. Is there a limit on memory. Can I adjust it somewhere?

Comment: That's likely the culprit then. See http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=image+php+memory+limit

Comment: I can display the images normally on the site. It's only when I call PHP thumb that the images don't display. This leads me to think it's not a memory issue. Any thoughts?

Comment: @user Any reason why you can't look inside the images' source code to find out what's happening? (Ryan's explanation above is a possibility too, though)

Comment: Not sure how to do this. How would I do this?

Comment: @user look for the line in the PHPThumb file where it emits the Content-type header and comment it out. Or try "view source" while seeing the broken image in the browser, although Chrome doesn't allow that any more